# Access to an application sharepoint from android

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I ask if there is an API Sharepoint that offers access from android app to sharepoint documents, or just a way that permit to me to access Sharepoint documents.

Comment: Why don't you write your own Middle-tier web service using Client Object Model to access the SharePoint stuff.. This service will work as a bridge between Android and SharePoint ?

Comment: Hi Arsalan
yeah that will be a good idea, but how we can write our own Middle-tier web service using Client Object Model to access the SharePoint, if you have a tutorial or an example of that i will be thankful.

Comment: I have posted it all as answer, if that helps please mark as correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own Middle-tier web service using Client Object Model to access the SharePoint stuff..

See [Basic Operations using Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

This service will work as a bridge between Android and SharePoint..

For more specific questions on Client object model operations, please post another questions..